# /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: 18.04

I am trying to setup SQL Server on Ubuntu 18.04, but I am getting the following error:

> /opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

entire log:

```
root@h2624478:~# sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup
Locale nl_NL not supported. Using en_US.
usermod: no changes
Choose an edition of SQL Server:
  1) Evaluation (free, no production use rights, 180-day limit)
  2) Developer (free, no production use rights)
  3) Express (free)
  4) Web (PAID)
  5) Standard (PAID)
  6) Enterprise (PAID) - CPU Core utilization restricted to 20 physical/40 hyperthreaded
  7) Enterprise Core (PAID) - CPU Core utilization up to Operating System Maximum
  8) I bought a license through a retail sales channel and have a product key to enter.

Details about editions can be found at
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=852748

Use of PAID editions of this software requires separate licensing through a
Microsoft Volume Licensing program.
By choosing a PAID edition, you are verifying that you have the appropriate
number of licenses in place to install and run this software.

Enter your edition(1-8): 3
The license terms for this product can be found in
/usr/share/doc/mssql-server or downloaded from:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=855862

The privacy statement can be viewed at:
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=853010


Choose the language for SQL Server:
(1) English
(2) Deutsch
(3) Español
(4) Français
(5) Italiano
(6) 日本語
(7) 한국어
(8) Português
(9) Русский
(10) 中文 – 简体
(11) 中文 （繁体）
Enter Option 1-11: 1
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
Configuring SQL Server...

This is an evaluation version.  There are [170] days left in the evaluation period.
** ERROR: Failed to create WinSta0; GLE=0x8
** ERROR: [AppLoader] Failed to load desktop: 0xc0000001
AppLoader: Exiting with status=0xc0000001
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Fri May  3 23:37:16 2019
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000006
      Message: Termination of \SystemRoot\system32\AppLoader.exe was due to fatal error 0xC0000001
      Address: 0x6b852c6e
   Stacktrace: 000000006b93263a 000000006b852b29 000000006b852c6e
               000000006b8521d8 000000006b8522bb 000000006b802eb9
               000000006b971008 0000000280234010
      Process: 3650 - sqlservr
       Thread: 3681 (application thread 0x70)
  Instance Id: 4e1589d3-72d0-40e9-b49c-836bbb340fc3
     Crash Id: e1fada63-074b-46f0-ab80-f411356d0382
  Build stamp: 53ceecd604098a2abee47183edbd7d4bc6065630a4d5742b04eef3004f6a7775
 Distribution: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
   Processors: 2
 Total Memory: 4294967296 bytes
    Timestamp: Fri May  3 23:37:16 2019

/opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
^C/opt/mssql/bin/handle-crash.sh: fork: Onderbroken systeemaanroep // I HIT CRTL +C HERE
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 361, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 357, in main
    processCommands()
  File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 262, in processCommands
    COMMAND_TABLE[args.which]()
  File "/opt/mssql/bin/../lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py", line 75, in handleSetup
    mssqlconfhelper.setupSqlServer(eulaAccepted, noprompt=args.noprompt)
  File "/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/mssqlconfhelper.py", line 1009, in setupSqlServer
    ret = configureSqlservrWithArguments("--setup --reset-sa-password", MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=encodedPassword, MSSQL_PID=pid)
  File "/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/mssqlconfhelper.py", line 913, in configureSqlservrWithArguments
    return subprocess.call(args, env=env)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1099, in wait
    pid, sts = _eintr_retry_call(os.waitpid, self.pid, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 125, in _eintr_retry_call
    return func(*args)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

What could be the problem?